# Traversing the DOM to change a sibling>child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
const $jq = $;

$jq('#section-a li').on('click', function() {
  const el = $jq(this);
  el.addClass("answerPick").siblings(".answer").removeClass("answerPick");
  
  if (el.hasClass("answerPick")) {
    el.children(".circle").addClass("circleVisited").parent(".answer").siblings(".answer").children("circle").removeClass("circleVisited");
  }
});
```

```css
.answerPick {
  
}

.circleVisited {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-a" class="questions active">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Is the Gift for a Man or Woman?
      <p>(CHOOSE ONE)</p>
    </legend>
    <ul>
      <li class="answer" data-url="male" data-select="1320072+"><img src="/Images/modules/bluehim_200x.jpg" class="baseimg">
        <p class="qText">Male</p>
        <p class="circle"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="answer" data-url="female" data-select="1320071+"> <img src="/Images/modules/blueher_200x.jpg" class="baseimg">
        <p class="qText">Female</p>
        <p class="circle"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to add a class of `circleVisited` to the child of (this) `li` when clicked, more specifically the p element with a class of circle . However only one `p` element can have the class `circleVisited` at a time per section.

If this `li` has a class of `answerPick` then find the child of that `li` with the class of `circle` and add the class `circleVisited`. Then check the parent elements with the class of "answer", check their children with the class of `circle` and remove the class `circleVisited` if present.

Apologies if I'm unclear. Please let me know if you need anymore information, I fear I'm missing something obvious and making this more difficult than necessary.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Please try to add debugger or a chrome debug point in the click handler, then first try to add a css class. Then in another line try to remove class from the siblings. Also, check if you are getting the element correctly or not

Comment: Much appreciated Prateek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `.circleAdded` to the children you could create a rule for it that takes into account the parent `li`'s style

```css
  li.answerPick > p.circle {
    /* Whatever you wanted .circle.circleVisited to look like */
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Mello, I knew there had to be a much more simple solution for this.